# Ruby printing all elements of a hash but last

Tags: ruby, hash, key

Say I have:

```
hash = {"a" => 1, "b" => 2, "c" => 3}

keys = hash.keys
```

In order to print all the keys you would do:

```
keys.each {|x| puts x}
```

My question is, how do you print all the keys BUT the last one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do as below using [`Enumerable#take`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-take) :

```
hash = {"a" => 1, "b" => 2, "c" => 3}
hash.take(hash.size-1).each do |k,_|
  p k
end
# >> "a"
# >> "b"
```

Or, as below :

```
hash = {"a" => 1, "b" => 2, "c" => 3}
hash.keys.take(hash.size-1) # => ["a", "b"]
puts hash.keys.take(hash.size-1)
# >> a
# >> b
```

**update** (As asked by OP - *Alright now how do I print just the last element explicitly?*)

```
hash = {"a" => 1, "b" => 2, "c" => 3}
hash.keys.last  # => "c"
```

[`Hash#keys`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Hash.html#method-i-keys) will give you all the keys of that hash as an *array*. So, now you can call [`Array#last`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-last) on that array to get the last element.

Comment: Alright now how do I print just the last element explicitlY?

Answer (score 0):

```
hash = {"a" => 1, "b" => 2, "c" => 3}

keys = hash.keys
keys[0..-2]
#=> ["a", "b"]
```

`[0..-2]` would index the array from the first to the one before the last

```
keys[0..-2].each { |x| puts x }
```

the last element in an array can be retrieved by calling `last` method on the array

```
keys.last
#=> "c"
```

Comment: Alright now how do I print just the last element explicitlY?